# Найти первую пятницу 13-е данного года

Tags: javascript

На входе функции год (числом)

Функция должна вернуть первую пятницу 13-е этого года в виде объекта Date

Пример:

```
console.log( third(2019) );
// Fri Sep 13 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Moscow Standard Time)
```

Помогите пожалуйста, уже целый день на это потратил

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <script>
  for (let friday of arrayOfFridaythe13thsIn(2019))
   console.log(friday.toLocaleString(undefined, { day: "numeric", month: "long" }))     
   function arrayOfFridaythe13thsIn(year) {
            let array = [];
            for (let month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
                let d = new Date(year, month, 13);
                if (d.getDay() == 5) {
                    array.push(d);
                }
            }
            return array;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```