# Как найти пятницу 13 по году?

Tags: javascript, дата

Код по идее должен прогонять объект `Date` с определенным годом и складывать в массив все **пятницы 13е**. Но в консоли выкидывает ошибку 400.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function GetDate(year) {
    for (var munth = 0; munth < 12; munth++) {
      var date = new Date(year, munth, 13);
      var res = [];
      if (date.getDay() === 5) res += date + "/n";
    }
    return res;
  }
  GetDate(2008);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1046909/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-13-%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0 - дубль...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function GetDate(year) {
    var res = [];
    for (var munth = 0; munth < 12; munth++) {
      var date = new Date(year, munth, 13);
      if (date.getDay() === 5) res.push(date);
    }
    return res;
  }

  var result = GetDate(2018);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.join("<br/>");
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: иногда возникает вопрос, а зачем отвечать на вопросы, у которых есть [явный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1046909/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-13-%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)? (без претензий, просто вопрос)